# Split array, extract only unique values, and then re-merge to array in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a dataset which has been grouped using this code:

```
select
array_to_string(array_agg(DISTINCT "Categories"), ',') as "Categories", "Name", ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as "ID"
from data1
group by "Name"
```

and it looks like this:

```
+----+--------+-----------------------------------------+
| ID | Name   | Categories                              |
+----+--------+-----------------------------------------+
| 1  | Class1 | Barry, Steve, Luke, Barry, Barry, Luke  |
+----+--------+-----------------------------------------+
| 2  | Class2 | Luke, Barry, Steve                      |
+----+--------+-----------------------------------------+
| 3  | Class3 | Gerald, Jacqueline, David, Barry, Barry |
+----+--------+-----------------------------------------+
```

I need to have only the unique values in "Categories". However, in the first row, the database considers `Barry, Steve, Luke` to be a string, and `Barry, Luke` to be a string, so using `DISTINCT` doesn't work to cut out the number of `Barry`s.

We need to split the string using the comma delimiter, but then re-aggregate it.

The output should look like:

```
+----+--------+-----------------------------------------+
| ID | Name   | Categories                              |
+----+--------+-----------------------------------------+
| 1  | Class1 | Barry, Steve, Luke                      |
+----+--------+-----------------------------------------+
| 2  | Class2 | Luke, Barry, Steve                      |
+----+--------+-----------------------------------------+
| 3  | Class3 | Gerald, Jacqueline, David, Barry        |
+----+--------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: It would be easier to do it while grouping not after grouping. Show the grouping step.

Comment: Edited to include - does that help?

Comment: Your code should be working already. I don't understand why it does not.

Comment: The code you posted does not include the id. Show the one you used to produce the grouped set.

Comment: Added - I'm redacting the original dataset to protect the innocent :)

Answer (score 0):

You can extract unique values with query like this

```
select 
  ID,
  Name,
  (
    select string_agg(c, ',') 
    from (
      select
        distinct trim(unnest(string_to_array(Categories, ',')))
    ) t (c)
  ) as Categories
from your_table_name;
```

But it's better to aggregate distinct values while grouping.